# Calling method continuously every 10 minutes in Typescript, Ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Is this possible to trigger a method every 10 minutes in typescript/angular2?

And second question, is this possible to call a method everytime local time reaches multiply of 10 minutes? Like:

```
5:00 then 5:10 then 5:20 then 5:30 then 5:40...
```

Comment: Yes it is. See [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using [**Reactive-Extensions/RxJS**](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/timer.md).

```
Rx.Observable.timer(dueTime, [period], [scheduler])
```

> Returns an observable sequence that produces a value after dueTime has
>   elapsed and then after each period.

This is just an example from the doc.Hope you can use it easily with your use case.

```
var source = Rx.Observable.timer(200, 100)
    .timeInterval()
    .pluck('interval')
    .take(3);

var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('Next: ' + x);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');
    });

// => Next: 200
// => Next: 100
// => Next: 100
// => Completed
```

Comment: The Reactive Extensions for JavaScript have no external dependencies on any library, so they'll work well with just about any library. @AluanHaddad

Comment: indeed but seeing as Angular requires the recent RxJS 5, why not leverage it? Is there some reason? (not liking it would be valid)